# PYTHON - ¿Como puedo generar un plano cartesiano mediante el uso de bucles anidados?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, bucle-for, bucles

mi duda es la siguiente, mientras estaba curioseando el tema de bucles anidados en python me tope con algunos ejercicios, en los cuales con el uso de listas y los dichos bucles, se podían crear triangulo, cuadrados, rectángulos, etc. Lo que yo quisiera realizar seria crear un plano cartesiano y que en el pueda crear diversas figurar geométricas y el reto es crear un circulo en el plano cartesiano, sin el uso de interfaz.

Mi avance es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
alto = 10
largo = 10

for a in range(alto):
  if a != alto - 1:
      for l in range(largo):
          if l is not 0:
              print(" ", end=' ')
          else:
              print(".",end=" ")
  else:
    for l in range(largo):
        print(".",end=" ")
  print('')
```

Este es un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade que has intentado o investigado por tu cuenta, además coloca tus dudas puntuales

Comment: Si, hasta ahora solo tengo el marco lo que me falta es poner las figurar adentro.

Comment: Tu pregunta solo se puede responder con dos loops anidados ?. No se te ocurrió usar `matplotlib `?

Comment: @StevenAngelCoailaZaa  Puedes usar el concepto de matrices en 2 dimensiones. El cero representa un espacio, el 1 un punto. Claro tiene limitaciones pero seguro se puede todas las figuras que menciones . Por ejemplo mira este enlace para crear un triangulo de Matrices: https://alunosonline.uol.com.br/matematica/matriz-triangular.html

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tratare de aplicarlo :)